# Does log4j2.8.2.jar work with JDK 1.7. How to find the supported jdk version for a jar file?

Tags: log4j, java-7

Does log4j2.8.2.jar work with JDK 1.7.
How to find the supported jdk version for a given jar file ? In my case i want to find the supported jdk version for log4j 2.8.2.jar.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.8.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.2</version>
     <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Java 7 is supported up to 2.12.1

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Requirements
Log4j 2.13.0 and greater require Java 8. Version 2.4 through 2.12.1 required Java 7 and versions 2.0-alpha1 to 2.3 required Java 6. Some features require optional dependencies; the documentation for these features specifies the dependencies.